# Cannot get google to crawl AJAX Hashbang site

Tags: php, ajax, seo, web-crawler, hashbang

I have been working on a project for a little over a month now and have spent a long time trying to really understand the ins and out of crawling ajax. I have built a site which uses .load() and '#!' (which I now know was sillt of me but oh well!) and have set up HTML snapshots to be generated when ?*escaped*... is requested. I have submitted a sitemap to Google and read through their documentation a thousand times over.

The site address is http://renewmywindows.com/

If i fetch the site as google it returns the correct html for the requested page but I am having a lot of issues with getting google to crawl it.

I have a feeling I have just forgotten to do one small thing that is throwing the rest off but I can't figure out for the life of me what it is...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

C

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like http://www.renewmywindows.com/#!home.php is in the google index and working

you can see this by googleing `site:renewmywindows.com`

It does seem to have some stale data? maybe try resubmitting your sitemap? 
are you getting any errors or warnings in google webmaster tools?

Also you might want to:

1. remove the 404 page from your sitemap
2. turn off php errors http://renewmywindows.com/?_escaped_fragment_=aabout-us.php

Comment: So if you could look at my site again real quick and answer me this? the returned snapshot, should the URL's for hyperlinks in the snapshot be pretty or ugly?

Comment: if by pretty you mean `/#!` and ugly `/?_escaped_fragment_`  you should always use pretty https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq#whentousewhich

Comment: Ok, I thought that was the case, not sure why I was stupid enough to put them as ugly!